# Solr - How to trigger the DIH from SolrNet API with C# code

Tags: solr, solrnet

**Solr version :: 6.6.1**

SolrNet API with the C# based application

I wish to invoke or trigger the data import handler from the C# code with
the help of SolrNet. But i am unable to locate any tutorial in the SolrNet
API. I can easily invoke the DIH from the solr admin UI, but my need is to invoke it from an external application.

Please suggest the code snippet how do i invoke the data import action from the C# based
application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do completely from Solr.NET, a brief look gives me an idea, that currently there is only class responsible for DIH status page, which is good, but not covering the initial process. I think this was discarded recently, since this functionality wasn't needed.

In the `SolrBasicServer` class you have:

```
public SolrDIHStatus GetDIHStatus(KeyValuePair<string, string> options) {
            var response = connection.Get("/dataimport", null);
            var dihstatus = XDocument.Parse(response);
            return dihStatusParser.Parse(dihstatus);
        }
```

which is getting the DIH. Most likely, you need to extend this class and do something similar (I'm not C# developer, so not 100% sure about the code):

```
connection.Post("/dataimport?command=full-import", null);
```

or something similar with `delta-import` command and then later get the status part.

If updating Solr.NET is not the case for you, you still could just trigger it via usual HTTP call with some preferable C# library and do POST request to `http://host:port/solr/collection-name/dataimport?command=full-import`

Comment: I think i would have to use the C# HttpClient class to call the Solr Rest API and trigger the action..

Comment: by saying HttpClient you mean just some client not the Solr related one, right?

Comment: Correct.. Any http based address can be invoked using the C# HttpClient class.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean by saying the last part of the answer - if you do not want to update Solr.NET (which 95% of the developers do not want to)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string solrTargetDIHUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/dih/dataimport?command=delta-import";

        try
        {                
            using (var solrClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var resultObj = solrClient.GetAsync(new Uri(solrTargetDIHUrl)).Result;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t Data Import Triggered Successfully !");
                Console.ResetColor();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR in DIH Trigger >>>>> " + ex.Message + "||" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```